# excel calculation excess 1 on one file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

There is a file that contains mathematical operations that are a bit complicated.

When the file is opened on my laptop the value of `500,000,000` changes to `500,000,001`, an excess of 1 number.

What exactly should I do?

I use Excel 2013, using an Asus X441U

Comment: Can't really help you with a formula you don't include.

Comment: So it only happens on your laptop? If you open the same file on another computer it doesn't change? And is this a hard-coded number, or the result of a formula ? If from formula, one solution is to use `ROUND`.

Comment: There are many articles written about how Excel works with big numbers and about the issues related to converting numbers to binary representation. E.g. this one on SU https://superuser.com/questions/1367025/in-excel-when-i-enter-22222-09482-then-i-see-22222-0948199999-number-in-the-for ; I am not sure, without more information from you, that this is the reason for your problem, but an interesting read anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is commonly a formatting problem.

Please make sure that you are obtaining the *real* value of the result, not the displayed value.

This is best done by changing the cell number formatting. I would recommend adding a helper cell or two to and use `=CELL("contents",yourcellwithchangingvalue)` as one test.

Another method is to make a second result cell and wrap it in `=TEXT(yourcellwithchangingvalue, "#.###")` to see if that causes it to change.

Lastly, be sure all of your formulas are using functions or addins that are available on both machines.